# Sending Unix/Linux SIGNAL through PIPE

Tags: linux, bash, signals, pipe

I want to sent a `SIGNAL` to a process after `.5` seconds.

Maybe this is not a good idea to do but I want to do it for an uncommon temporary case.

I tried like following, but its not working.

```
(sleep .5;kill -9)| some_process
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sleep .5; kill -9 $(pidof some_process)`  should work. `pidof` returns a process id for a process name. The `$()` returns the result of the command to the `kill` command. An alternative would be:

`sleep .5; pidof some_process | xargs kill -9`

check `man pidof` for details.

Edit: there is also `timeout`. `timeout -s SIGKILL 0.5s some_process` should do the trick if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: No. I want to kill the process which is after this `PIPE`. This `some_process` is not a different process.

Comment: Basically, I will not get the pid of `some_process`. So need to sent  `SIGNAL` through pipe to `some_process`

Comment: So the process should start and should be killed after `0.5` seconds? Maybe `man timeout` helps here? `timeout -k` e.g.?

Comment: why can't you get the pid? Could you clarify the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Signals aren't directed to pipes; they're directed to process identifiers (pids). I might try something like this:

```
some_process & sleep .5; kill -KILL $!
```

which would run `some_process` in the background (that's what the `&` is for). After half a second, it will used the variable `$!` which indicates the pid of the last backgrounded process.

(Although `sleep` on some systems only accepts an integer.)